# python консоль - не работает история команд, нельзя исправить написанный код в конктретном месте

Tags: python, linux, консоль, centos

На сервере стоит `python`, `django`. Но работать в ней неудобно, ибо если опечатался, то приходится заново печатать код, потому что при нажатии стрелки влево отображается символ `^[[D` и выглядит это так

```
Python 3.8.11 (default, Jan 10 2022, 11:59:57) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> ^[[D
  File "<console>", line 1
    
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print('test')
test
>>> ^[[A
  File "<console>", line 1
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print('test)^[[1;2D
  File "<console>", line 1
    print('test)
                     ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Как пофиксить эту дичь, чтобы можно было нормально работать в консоли ?

Подключаюсь по `ssh`

```
ssh <user>@<host>
```

Линукс, Centos 7, Python 3.8.11

---

UPD:

```
# python3 -m sysconfig

Platform: "linux-x86_64"
Python version: "3.8"
Current installation scheme: "posix_prefix"

Paths: 
    ...

Variables: 
    ...
    HAVE_LIBIEEE = "0"
    HAVE_LIBINTL_H = "1"
    HAVE_LIBREADLINE = "0"
    HAVE_LIBRESOLV = "0"
    HAVE_LIBSENDFILE = "0"
    HAVE_LIBUTIL_H = "0"
    ...
```

Comment: Собственно, самое важное и не написали. Чем и откуда подключаетесь к серверу? Потому что эта, как вы выразись, "дичь" происходит на вашей стороне.

Comment: обновил вопрос, по `ssh`

Comment: @ZaArs, откуда питон? скорей всего, он собран без поддержки readline'а… `python3 -m sysconfig` в студию для подтверждения…

Comment: @Fat-Zer обновил

Comment: Увидел `HAVE_LIBREADLINE = 0`

Comment: спасибо. решил проблему `pip install readline`

оформлю как ответ, если не будет ответа от вас

Comment: @ZaArs оформляй...

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в отсутствии библиотеки `readline`, что выяснилось командой `python3 -m sysconfig`.

```
    ...
    HAVE_LIBINTL_H = "1"
    HAVE_LIBREADLINE = "0"
    HAVE_LIBRESOLV = "0"
    ...
```

Установил недостающую библиотеку через `pip install readline`

Проблема решена

Comment: А по-хорошему надо поставить `ipython`, и забыть о проблемах.